# Printing a webpage

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

I currently have 2 options on my website, a user can print the page they are viewing to PDF (utilising DOMPDF) or they can just print the website straight to the printer for which i use `window.print()` however the two options seem to have differing results, the PDF prints out as a4 however `window.print()` seems to print out that less than that at around a5 size.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason could be that `window.print()` just checks where the page is finishing and then cuts it off till there and makes a print out. When I try to print my webpages they give me the size around a4 size. It could be just because of the resolution of the screen of how big or small it is. Whereas the PDF print option knows about the whole page and then makes it of a legal paper size and then sends a print.

Comment: really? screen resolution makes a difference?